# PLC Communication with raspberry pi and hamachi

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi, iptables, plc, hamachi

The system that I am attempting to set up consists of several PLCs hooked up via Ethernet to a Raspberry Pi. The Pi is then connected to Hamachi VPN (I use hamachi because we do not have and external ip to use for other VPN solutions. If there is another alternative I an open to trying). On the other end there is a PC connected to the Hamachi network. I need to be able to talk (ping and connect) with the PLCs hooked to the Pi. I have been able to use iptables to get the PC to talk to one PLC but not through its own ip but buy pointing the software at the hamachi ip. I can get it to the point of pinging the PC from the PLC using iptables but not the other way around. My endgame is to be able to access the PLC from the PC using the PLC's ip over hamachi vpn. Any ideas or direction?

```
-------------              -------------              -----------
|    PLC    |_____(eth0)___|   RasPi   |____(ham0)____|    PC   |
|           | (eventually  |           |              |         |
-------------  will have   -------------              -----------
               switch here)      | (eth1)                  |
                                 |                         |
                             ------------__________________|
                             | Internet |
                             ------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing [OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi) on your pi, then attempt to configure it to do some NAPT routing where it picks a specific PLC to communicate with based on the port number that the pi was accessed with. I'm not sure you can use a hamachi VPN to connect using a manually configured port number, but you could certainly do that with a regular TCP connection.

Also, it might be worth looking at some of the answers in this post:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/243/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-router

Instead of installing OpenWRT, you can just implement a few routing features that suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into it. The biggest issue and the reason I need something similar to hamachi is that I can't access the network remotely via ip address. It will have an internet connection but I wont be able to forward ports all the way in. But I will check into OpenWRT and see if it will fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hamachi
Ok guys, latest working version is 2.1.0.8.6, newer versions will get you segmentation fault errors.

I uploaded it for you, it is a debfile

http://ul.to/ppisqm61

Instead of install.sh I used the following, install.sh might also work but that's the way I did it:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends --force-architecture logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.86-1_armel.deb
```